# How do I playback .m4s files. And turn them into a binary stream for a Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, discord.js, mpeg-dash

I want to download the BBC radio 2 and stream it to a discord server. Each request is https://as-dash-uk-live.akamaized.net/pool_904/live/uk/bbc_radio_two/bbc_radio_two.isml/dash/bbc_radio_two-audio=320000-250636302.m4s However the Time stamp will change and they regularly delete content. I found a .dash file as well https://as-dash-uk-live.akamaized.net/pool_904/live/uk/bbc_radio_two/bbc_radio_two.isml/dash/bbc_radio_two-audio=320000.dash which is seems to request. However I can't find how to send it through a discord bot to a discord server. My code is

```js
const axios = require('axios')


module.exports = {
    play: async function (guild,message) {
        const serverQueue = {};
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
        serverQueue.connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        plays(guild)
        
        async function plays(guild) {
            let data1 = new Date(1353439725);
            let data2 = new Date(Date.now()/1000);
            console.log(`https://as-dash-uk-live.akamaized.net/pool_904/live/uk/bbc_radio_two/bbc_radio_two.isml/dash/bbc_radio_two-audio=320000-${Math.floor((data2 - data1))-4000}.m4s`)
            const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play((await axios.get(`https://as-dash-uk-live.akamaized.net/pool_904/live/uk/bbc_radio_two/bbc_radio_two.isml/dash/bbc_radio_two-audio=320000-${Math.floor((data2 - data1))-4000}.m4s`)).data)
                .on('finish', () => {
                    console.log('Music ended!');
                    plays(guild);
                    return
                })
                .on('error', error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    plays(guild);
                    return
                });
            dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
        }
    }
}
```

However no audio plays and the audio end event is always being called. Am I being really stupid or is there a way to do this.

Comment: Can you actually play the M4S file in a new tab (_eg:_ using Chrome)? I suspect the file is domain-locked to be only be served to requests coming from the BBC server (eg: their own player asking for the file). I don't use Discord so don't know if an `iFrame` is a possible option.

Comment: Using axios I am able to get the data in a get request (you need a UK IP not get a 403 error) but you can use a get request.

Comment: Are you saying the problem is solved and you get playing audio data using axios? The only working link I got is an `HTTP` link to the audio stream but I don't know if Discord allows loading of non `HTTPS` links. Also for some reason the Radio 2 site wants me to "sign in" to play their live stream since yesterday (so no further debugging possible).